# Find elements which aren't in other list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find values of string which aren't includes into other list.

I have list like:

```
var list1 = new List<string>();
        list1.Add("element1");
        list1.Add("element2");


var list2 = new List<string>();
        list2.Add("element1");
        list2.Add("element2");
        list2.Add("element3");
```

I need to find elements from list2 which aren't in list1, so the result should be only:`element3`. I tried to do something like right join with LINQ, but it was unsuccessful. Maybe someone know proper  solution for this?

Comment: What, specifically, did you try, and what problems did you have with that attempted solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
var result = list2.Except(list1);
```

Another way of doing that could be:

```
var result = list2.Where(r => !list1.Contains(r));
```

If you need a `List<string>` as result, then just add `ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.Except(list2)
```

Returns the set difference between 2 IEnumerables: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var list3 = list2.Except(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list2.Except(List1)
```

.Except() should work